# How to find out the source of a request (in chrome dev tools)?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I have a weird network request in my page, which refers to JavaScript files, which I removed from every html file earlier. Cache is cleared and there is no single reference to be found in the source html and the JavaScript files. For fixing that and also out of general curiosity I would like to know if there is a simple way to find out where a request was triggered, preferably using the chrome-devtools.

**Update:**
Thanks to jaredwilli I found the initator column under the network-tab. However this only shows `Other`. What I would like to know, is the (html or javascript) file where those Requests have been triggered.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

On the Network panel, you can determine what the initiator of a request was by viewing the Initiator column. It gives you the file, line number and type of resource it was, either Script or something else.

Comment: That is the correct answer. However it only shows ```Other```. Any idea what that could mean?

Comment: Ok, sorry I had a change of mind and updated the question as ```Other``` is shown for many requests and I also need to know where they are triggered.

Comment: When a requests fails (such as a Page Not Found `404` error), it doesn't seem like this Network tab in DevTools indicates where in the code the request was triggered from. The **Initiator** sub-tab only shows a tree-like list that doesn't even jump to the JS call (even 9 years later! imagine...)